# Bootstrap 2 carousel second slide disappears

Tags: carousel, twitter-bootstrap-2

We are using Bootstrap 2 on a Joomla 3.2.2 site. See: http://test.stuntlist.com/west

The first slide works perfectly, but when the second slide comes in, it disappears. You can see it start to transition between the slides, but then the area where the slide should be just disappears and the content is moved up into the slide area.

I don't see any JS errors on the site. We have used the same carousel code on other sites without this issue.

Here is the carousel code:

```
    <div class="slideshow">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
          <a href="/component/joomgallery/action-photos?Itemid=88"><span data-picture data-alt="">
            <span data-src="/images/hero/slide01.jpg"></span>
            <span data-src="/images/hero/portrait/slide01mobile.jpg" data-media="(max-width: 768px) and (orientation:portrait)"></span>
            <noscript><img src="/images/hero/slide01.jpg" alt=""></noscript>
          </span></a>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="container">
            <h4>Slide Caption Goes Here.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="item">
          <span data-picture data-alt="">
            <span data-src="/images/hero/slide02.jpg"></span>
            <span data-src="/images/hero/portrait/slide02mobile.jpg" data-media="(max-width: 768px) and (orientation:portrait)"></span>
            <noscript><img src="/images/hero/slide02.jpg" alt=""></noscript>
          </span>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="container">
            <h4>Second Caption.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what could be causing the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused due to a conflict with Mootools, download the following plugin and apply your preferences and it'll resolve this problem:

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/mootools-enabler-disabler

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Joomla adds another DIV (We will call it JDIV) outside the Carousel container, when second/EVEN Numbered Slides are viewed some script sets the height of the JDIV equal to "0px", see my code below

```
<div class="col-sm-12 pharma"> 

<!-- this is the div which joomla is adding (JDIV) -->
<div style="margin: 0px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 0px;">
<!-- this is the div which joomla is adding (JDIV) -->

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="margin: -203px 0px 0px; overflow: hidden;"> 
        <div class="carousel-inner">  
            ....
        </div>  
        <div class="ind-div">    
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                ....
            </ol>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

**The Solution**

This solution worked for me and should also work for you too.

Add a CSS class named "#myCarousel" ( ID of the carousel) and sets its margin to 0px with important,

**`#myCarousel{ margin:0px !important; }`**

Secondly add another CSS class like

**`.pharma>div{ height:204px !important; }`**

where **.pharma** is the class which I have used on the DIV which is outside the JDIV. The height will be different from what I have used and might have to use media queries if using responsive.

To find the height simply inspect the element and note the height of the first slide and use that height in CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a fix for you but I was able to find a few issues. The first and biggest issue being that you have inline styling that is causing the image to "disappear". The image is really just moved 572px upwards and is off the screen. Notice the two images below. The first link is the image that does work. The second link is the image that does not display.

http://tinypic.com/r/hthi4y/8

http://tinypic.com/r/2hoix35/8

Using chrome, I opened the developer console and manually changed the margin to 0px instead of -572px and it fixed the issue. I would take a look at your JS again and see what values are being applied to each image because the entire display is being rendered dynamically, I assume for mobile devices.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The inline styles must be being added by the Bootstrap carousel JS. Don't know why it would be any different from any other site using the carousel.

Comment: Yea, I am not sure on the why. Is it possible for you to upgrade to TBS 3.X?